# How to make a one to seven relationship, with only one of the seven types in each - Entity-Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have a model called "Week" that has a list of "Day" and a day has an Enum "DayOfWeek" which has "Monday", "Tuesday", "Thursday", "Friday" and "Sunday"

### "Week" Model

```
public class Week
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    //This needs to be only able to have one "Monday" one "Tuesday" etc 
    public virtual List<Day.Day> DaysOfTheWeek { get; set; }
}
```

### "Day" Model

```
public class Day
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public Week.Week Week { get; set; }
    //This is my key (for "week") each week should only have one "Monday", one "Tuesday", etc
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Class.Class> Classes { get; set; }
}
```

Each "Week" should only be able to have one of each of the types of "Day", one "Monday", one "Tuesday", one "Wednesday" etc
How can I achieve this with data annotations/relationships
Thanks, From Dylan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve this in two ways:

1. Using validation only

Implement `IValidatableObject`and check the uniqueness of days in there.

2. Using a composite primary key on `Day`, which includes the `Week` ID and the `DayOfWeek`.

This will put the constraint on the physical model and conceptually make `Day` a "child entity" of `Week`.

You can do something like this (you may need to adjust, I didn't have time to try it out):

```
public class Day
{
  public Week.Week Week { get; set; }
  [Key] 
  [Column(Order = 2)] 
  public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }
  public virtual List<Class.Class> Classes { get; set; }

  [Key] 
  [Column(Order=1)] 
  // Helper for PK; EF will recognize this as the FK by convention
  public string WeekId { get; set; }
}
```

You can also do a similar configuration via [the fluent interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620) instead of using the attributes.